# how to drop subpartition in mysql

Tags: mysql

I have a table with createddate and i had created a subpartition on the createddate like this:

```
    ALTER TABLE tablename
     PARTITION BY RANGE( YEAR(CreatedDate) )
        SUBPARTITION BY HASH(MONTH(CreatedDate) ) (

PARTITION p2015 VALUES LESS THAN (2016) (
            SUBPARTITION dec_2015,
            SUBPARTITION jan_2015,
            SUBPARTITION feb_2015,
            SUBPARTITION mar_2015,
            SUBPARTITION apr_2015,
            SUBPARTITION may_2015,
            SUBPARTITION jun_2015,
            SUBPARTITION jul_2015,
            SUBPARTITION aug_2015,
            SUBPARTITION sep_2015,
            SUBPARTITION oct_2015,
            SUBPARTITION nov_2015
```

Now I want to delete all data that the createddate less than June 2015, which means dropping the 5 subpartitions (I have tried deleting the data directly but since the table is too large it takes a lot of time deleting them). What should I use to drop those subpartitions?

Answer (score 2):

Dropping a partition is not possible with `HASH()` (because the assignment to a partition would change with the number of total partitions), see [ALTER TABLE Partition Operations](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/alter-table-partition-operations.html):

> DROP PARTITION can be used to drop one or more RANGE or LIST partitions. This statement cannot be used with HASH or KEY partitions

Instead, you can use `truncate` to delete all data in specific partitions at once:

```sql
alter table tablename truncate partition jan_2015, feb_2015,
               mar_2015, apr_2015, may_2015;
```

`Truncate` will basically drop and recreate your partition(s), thus deleting its content in milliseconds.

If you have values for 2014, they will be, despite the name of your partitions, assigned by month too, so values for e.g. december 2014 will remain (in partition `dec_2015`).

Unfortunately, for subpartitions `truncate` does not work prior to 5.7.2:

> Prior to MySQL 5.7.2, TRUNCATE PARTITION did not work with subpartitions (Bug #14028340, Bug #65184).

In this case, you would have to update mysql first - or stick with `delete`, and maybe delete rows per day (by a script), if it takes too long to delete a whole month.